# Is there an official documentation on the Date object that is used in couchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I did not find any documentation on the Date object that is used within a map function of a couchDB view. There is some strange behaviour that I encountered and I need some closure.

Following code:

```
emit(doc.type, { date: new Date() })
```

outputs:

```
{ date: "2012-03-10T18:57:32.408Z" }
```

Yet using:

```
emit(doc.type, { date: new Date("1984-12-10") })
```

outputs:

```
{ date: "Invalid Date" }
```

So what Date object is couchDB using here? It cannot be the JavaScript one, because new Date("1984-12-10") works there. couchDB however expects the date in a "1984/12/10" format.

Does anybody has any information concerning this issue?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1280

Comment: What version of CouchDb are you using?

Comment: Thank rwilliams for the link. I am using version 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB's views are parsed with [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey). I believe CouchDB 1.1.1 added support for a much newer version of SpiderMonkey(1.8.5). It's quite possible you are still running an older version of SpiderMonkey that doesn't properly handle `Date()` as you would expect. I don't know anything about your platform so I cannot recommend an upgrade path but I believe this is what you're experiencing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight on that topic. I am using Windows XP. I will try a newer version eventually.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You obviously were not following the previous conversation between rwilliams and me